# Error de compilación por la consola de comandos windows: "Could not find or load main class ColourPrint.class"

Tags: java, windows, class, compilador

Me da un error de ejecución en la consola de comandos de Windows cuando ejecuto cualquier programa ".java".
Me ha salido desde que intenté compilar un ".java" pasándole por parámetros un fichero de texto.
Por ejemplo: java medianumeros.java numeros.txt.

A partir de ahí, no me compila ninguna aplicación.
Si ejecuto "java ColourPrint.class" me sale por pantalla el siguiente error:

Error: Could not find or load main class ColourPrint.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ColourPrint.class

Sin embargo, en Eclipse si me lo ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: ¿Pertenece esa clase a algún paquete? ¿Qué versión de Java estás usando? Te recomiendo leer [ask], completar el [tour] y leer lo que es un [mcve]